# Using VS Isolated Shell as UI scaffolding

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk, visual-studio-shell

I am exploring the possibility of using Visual Studio isolated shell as UI scaffolding for my WPF application. The application will contain custom "document" windows as well as many side tool windows used to display extra information. I need the tool windows and document windows to either be controlled by a main controller or easily communicate with one another.

There are VERY FEW documentations on VS isolated shell and even fewer examples. So I am hoping that someone with previous experience in developing custom apps or IDEs using VS isolated shell can help me with this.

Is it feasible to use VS isolated shell just for its UI scaffolding purposes? If so, how can I essentially erase all of the inherited features from Visual Studio and custom everything from menu bars to document pages? Or is it better to use some other UI scaffolding library, such as AvalonDocks? The benefit of using VS shell is that it's much more stable and I can easily port it into Visual Studio as a custom tool window if I need to.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at recent samples from the Visual Studio Development team:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2014/05/30/vs-2013-sdk-samples-released.aspx